# php header function isn't working

Tags: php

I've tried to use ob_start(); and exit(); ,both are not working, please advise, thank you very much

```
<?php 
    ob_start();

    // connect to the database
    include('connect-db.php');

    // check if the form has been submitted.
    // If it has, start to process the form and save it to the database
    // once saved, redirect back to the view page
    if (isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {
        foreach ($_POST['patientid'] as $index => $patientid)
        {
            $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id'][$index]);
            $data1 = mysql_real_escape_string($patientid);
            $data2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['vaccineid'][$index]);
            $data3 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['vaccinename1'][$index]);
            $data4 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['vaccinename2'][$index]);
            $data5 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['vaccinename3'][$index]);
            $data6 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['totalnoofinjection'][$index]);
            $data7 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['nthinjection'][$index]);
            $data8 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['date'][$index]);
            $data9 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['nextdate'][$index]);
            $data10 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['skip'][$index]);
            $data11 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['language'][$index]);         

            mysql_query("UPDATE patientvaccinedetail SET patientid = '$data1',
                vaccineid = '$data2', vaccinename1 = '$data3',
                vaccinename2 = '$data4', vaccinename3 = '$data5',
                totalnoofinjection = '$data6', nthinjection = '$data7',
                date = '$data8', nextdate = '$data9', skip = '$data10', 
                language = '$data11'
                WHERE id=$id") or die(mysql_error());

            header("Location: start.php");
            exit;
        }
    }
```

Just updated and still cant't redirect to another pages

Comment: running on localhost or live ?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "not working"

Comment: **Please** stop using `mysql_*` functions as they are deprecated and completely removed in PHP7!

Comment: What exactly wasn't working, since it might help future readers.

Comment: Also its better practice (and more secure) to use [parameterized queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712037/what-is-parameterized-query) instead of concatenating your values into your query string. It also makes your code a bit tidier to boot.

Comment: running on localhost. Not working as the data could be saved but cant redirect to another page.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing semi colon after `exit`

Corrected code:

`exit;`

Answer (score 1):

use `ob_end_clean();` before the header call and use `exit;` instead of `exit`

> try like below

```
ob_end_clean();
 header("Location: start.php");
exit;
```

Comment: will the exit actually be executed though since the header line redirects to a different page?

Comment: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\inetpub\wwwroot\June21\displaypatient.php:58) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\June21\displaypatient.php on line 136

Comment: @tam you have echo anything in db connection file